# Flink's rich function's open method

Tags: apache-flink

My understanding of the `open()` method is that it is called once upon operator initialization. My question here is wouldn't declaring a `static final` variable also be essentially the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question here is wouldn't declaring a static final variable also be essentially the same?

Yes, but it depends what you are statically defining.

The key difference is that `open()` function gives you access to the underlying Flink runtime context, which can be necessary depending on your specific function and what you are defining (e.g, accessing runtime parameters, state, metrics, etc).

For instance, if you wanted to define a database connection using runtime parameters for your job, you’d open the connection within the function itself (likewise, you’d also want to define a corresponding symmetric `close()` function to handle disposing of those same resources).

If you are using constant values for all of your static instances (and don’t require any state or runtime parameters), you may not need to initialize them in the `open()` function. It ultimately all depends on what you are trying to do. Generally, I’d err towards using `open()` whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple slots per TaskManager, then each instance of your operator (which runs in a separate slot) gets a separate `open()` call, while if you're using a `static final` then there's only one of these per JVM (and thus one per Task Manager), so you'd only get a single initialization.

And separately, as Rion noted, you have access to the Flink runtime infrastructure in the `open()` call, via `getRuntimeContext()`.